# SQL-TRIGGER FAZENDO AUTO NUMERAÇÃO ERRADA

Tags: sql, trigger, sql-insert

Olá, estou estudando sql a pouquíssimo tempo então me desculpe se alguma nomenclatura não estiver ok.

Criei algumas triggers para meu banco de testes e em alguns casos está funcionando perfeitamente.
Em outros no entanto está criando sequencias erradas.
TENHO A TABELA CLIENTES POR EXEMPLO.
Onde criei a tabela e criei uma sequencia

**CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_CLI START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 NOMAXVALUE;**

Após criei a Trigger

**CREATE TRIGGER "TRG_CLIENTE1"
  BEFORE INSERT ON "CLIENTE"
  FOR EACH ROW
   BEGIN 
       SELECT "SEQ_CLI". NEXTVAL INTO:NEW.COD_CLI
       FROM DUAL;
  END;**

Agora fazendo INSERT na tabela de cliente o primeiro COD_CLI gerado é 16, e não tem nada inserido antes disso.
Se alguém puder ajudar no que possa estar acontecendo agradeço.
Obs: Fiz todas as triggers e sequences da mesma maneira.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma sequência, assim como o auto incremento, propositalmente pula os valores se eles tiverem sido excluídos em algum lugar do tempo. Por exemplo:

```
Criou o registro 13
Criou o registro 14
Deletou o registro 14
Criou o registro 15
```

Veja que mesmo ao excluir o registro com ID 14, o próximo a ser criado não será o 14, porém o 15.

O conceito de ID é pra ser único. Pode gerar inúmeros problemas se você reutilizar um ID, mesmo que ele tenha sido excluído.

Comment: Certo, entendi a questão, vai estar pulando IDs já usados.
Neste caso não foi excluído registros anteriores, o primeiro registro lançado começou no ID 16.
Mas na minha instrução eu havia feito para começar no 1. Sabes me dizer oque poder ter acontecido de errado?
Agradeço a atenção.

Comment: Você está compartilhando esse mesmo sequence (CREATE SEQUENCE) em outras tabelas?

Comment: Não usei em outras tabelas, porém quando estava inserindo fiz algumas tentativas até conseguir inserir, pois estava faltando alguma coisa, virgulas, parenteses etc, deve ter sido isso.
agradeço.

Comment: Atente também que Sequences garantem unicidade e não integridade , assim os "ids" podem perder a sequencia, algumas aplicações (Nota Fiscais , Núm de Apocices etc) não permitem isto e outra solução deve ser feita.